# How to drop multiple tables with common prefix in one query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, drop-table

I'm using  Microsoft SQL Server 2008.My question is:How to drop multiple tables with common prefix in one query?

something like that table names:

```
LG_001_01_STLINE, 
LG_001_02_STFICHE
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can build up a string using the catalog views, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += '
DROP TABLE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(s.name)
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
    WHERE t.name LIKE 'LG_001%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of course there are potential gotchas, for example if these tables have foreign key relationships, you'll either need to drop them first, or arrange the output to drop the tables in a certain order.

To just get the list of tables, use:

```
SELECT s.name, t.name 
  FROM sys.tables AS t 
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
  WHERE t.name LIKE 'LG_001%';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for remembering about "arrange the output to drop the tables in a certain order"!

Answer (score 6):

I ran this query then pasted the results back into query window to drop all the tables:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + NAME from sys.tables
ORDER BY NAME
```

If you want to delete all tables but keep those with names that started with A, B, C or D:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + NAME from sys.tables
WHERE NAME NOT LIKE '[ABCD]%'
GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to delete Multiple Tables at once:

DECLARE @CODE NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @XML XML

```
SET @XML = STUFF((
            SELECT ' ' + data.CODE_DELETE
            FROM (
                SELECT CONCAT ('DROP TABLE ', '[',table_schema,']', '.', '[',TABLE_NAME,']', ';') AS CODE_DELETE
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE table_schema + '.' + TABLE_NAME NOT IN  ( 
'[Schema].[Tablename]'

)
and Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
                ) [data]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
SET @CODE = CAST(@XML AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT @CODE
```

Answer (score -1):

This allows you to delete a much greater number of tables.

```
declare 
@cursor as cursor, 
@FTABLE as varchar(500) 
set @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
select 'drop table ' + NAME + ';' 
from sys.tables 
where not SUBSTRING(NAME,10,3) in 
( 
'310', 
'311', 
'312', 
'313', 
'314', 
'320', 
'321', 
'322' 
) 
open @cursor 
fetch next from @cursor into @FTABLE 
while (@@FETCH_STATUS =0) 
begin 
        exec(@FTABLE) 
        print @FTABLE 
fetch next from @cursor into @FTABLE 
end 
close @cursor 
deallocate @cursor
```

Comment: Greater than what?  Could you modify your SQL so that it looks for tables with a common prefix, like OP asked for?

Answer (score -1):

I like this one that I wrote:

```
  DECLARE @chv_LG001_TableName nvarchar (100)
  DECLARE @chv_DROP_LG001_Tables nvarchar(100)
  DECLARE @chv_LG001_Table_Count int

  SET @chv_LG001_Table_Count = (SELECT count(OBJECT_NAME(id))
        FROM SYSINDEXES
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(id,'isUserTable')=1 AND indid < 2
            and OBJECT_NAME(id) like 'LG_001%')

 IF @chv_LG001_Table_Count > 0
    BEGIN

    DECLARE  Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor CURSOR FOR
      -- This query will give you the table list you are wanting
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
        FROM SYSINDEXES
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(id,'isUserTable')=1 AND indid < 2
            and OBJECT_NAME(id) like 'LG_001%'

    OPEN Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor INTO @chv_LG001_TableName 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

    BEGIN           

    SET @chv_DROP_LG001_Tables = 'DROP TABLE ' + '[' + @chv_LG001_TableName + ']'

    --Print @chv_DROP_LG001_Tables 
-- Uncomment the next line when you are ready because it WILL clear out these tables. 
    --EXEC sp_executesql @chv_DROP_LG001_Tables

    FETCH NEXT FROM Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor
    INTO @chv_LG001_TableName

    END

    CLOSE Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Drop_LG001_Tables_Cursor

END
```

Comment: So many issues here. (1) The cursor scaffolding is complex and unnecessary. (2) When you do use a firehose cursor, you should at least use `STATIC` and/or `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options). (3) You shouldn't be using deprecated, backward compatibility views like `sysindexes`. (4) Your script assumes all tables are in the `dbo` schema (or worse, the default schema of the executing user, which may not even be `dbo`).

Answer (score -2):

This can be done using `execute` as follows:

```
declare @sql1 nvarchar(max) 
SELECT @sql1 =
 STUFF(
  (
    select ' drop table dbo.[' + name + ']'

FROM         sys.sysobjects AS sobjects
WHERE     (xtype = 'U') AND (name LIKE 'GROUP_BASE_NEW_WORK_%')
        for xml path('')
   ),
        1,1,'')

        execute sp_executesql @sql1
```

Comment: This is essentially a variation, but without any improvement, on the accepted answer. The difference is merely that you've chosen to assume that *1)* the default schema is supposed to be `dbo`, and *2)* the names can never contain a `]` – both of which may well be true in the OP's case but it would still be a good idea to mention those assumptions, because the caveats that follow from them might not be entirely obvious to other people. Still, as I said at the beginning, my principal issue with this answer is that it just restates an already existing suggestion without adding any new value.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT s.name, t.name 
  FROM sys.tables AS t 
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
  WHERE t.name LIKE 'LG_001%';
```

Run above query and save results into a csv. Then open that CSV in a notepad. Then do Ctrl+H to replace schema with DROP TABLE SCHEMA that will give you all the drop queries, copy and paste this big sql into your sql tool and execute

if your results are

```
myschema.table1
myschema.table2
```

after replace, it'll look like this

```
DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.TABLE1
DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.TABLE2
```

Comment: -1 Why would you do copy/paste in Excel and generate drop commands ? You can easily do it using `PRINT` statement. How is your answer better than the highest voted answer ?