# Is there an easy way to delete all records in multiple tables (but not every table)?

Tags: sql-server-2016, delete

So I "fixed" an issue the other day, which has caused a snowball of new issues (imagine that). I have a large group of tables that serve as Temp tables for many import/export processes that flow to other systems. Each table is labeled "TO_xxxx". I want to clear all records from each "TO_" table. Is there a way to structure a delete statement to clear all records from only "TO_" tables?

Is it as easy as

```
Delete from TO_%
```

or is there more to it? There's about 80 "TO_" tables total, so I figured I'd post here before manually going through everything. If you can help, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

System is SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5527/60085), which `drops` tables with a common prefix, you could use something like this

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += '
DELETE FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(s.name)
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
    WHERE t.name LIKE 'to[_]%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

The above example *prints* the `delete` commands.  When you are ready to actually run it, uncomment the `EXEC`